# How to sum one column in gridview and show it in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As        System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mcbdatabseConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mcbdatabse.subject_enrolled")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt
                        GridView1.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
     End If
End Sub
```

I have this code for my gridview, I want to total all the units and show it on my textbox;txtTotalUnits Thanks.[This is my gridview and textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0S1p.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an event handler for the **GridView.RowDataBound** **Event** as follows

```
Dim total as Integer

Sub CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles CustomersGridView.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

      total = total + Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells(the_column_index).Text) .
      txtTotalUnits.Text = Convert.ToString(total)

    End If

  End Sub
```

More similar examples on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Im having an error, Value of type Strings cannot be 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox

Comment: I fixed the error, but it doesnt show any result ont the textbox?

Comment: Have you actually added the method as an event handler to your GridView.RowDataBound event? I just edited my answer and added a Handles clause to the declaration of the method. Substitute the GridView's name with your GridView name adn try again

Comment: Gab you are wlecome: happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use the datasource table, you need `using System.Linq;`

```
var result = tbl.AsEnumerable().
                 Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x["ColumnNameForWhichYouWantSum"].ToString()));

txtTotalUnits.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: What is tbl.AsEnumerable()?

Comment: I dont know how to convert this codes to vb.net codes?

Comment: @Gab check this linq for VB.NET and C# implementations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mcbdatabseConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
      Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mcbdatabse.subject_enrolled")
        Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
          cmd.Connection = con
          sda.SelectCommand = cmd                    
          Using dt As New DataTable()
            sda.Fill(dt)
            Dim total As Integer = 0
            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
              Dim drw As DataRow = dt.Rows(i)
              Dim units As Integer = CInt(drw("Units")) 'Assuming Units is the column name'
              total += units
            Next i
            txtTotalUnits.Text = total.ToString
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()       
          End Using
        End Using
      End Using
    End Using
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But in asp.net you cant use DataGridView1.Rows. Can I import something to enable this?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I missed that this was ASP.NET

Comment: Sorry, I'm a goose, just sum up on the datatable instead. I've edited my answer

Comment: Should I declare this first Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()? cause Im having an error"sda is not declared" Im using this code on a button? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should replace the `Using dt as New DataTable` block in your original code. I've edited to show the whole code block